# table header colspan fix location scrollable

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having the issue where my colspan header is going behind my default header when I scroll down on my table. How do I fix this?

Also, it appears that on page load, the top of the scroll bar is higher than the top of the table, so when I scroll down the whole table moves up a bit. Not sure why that is.

I've attached some images down below. (P.S. This is for intro to web dev class, keep it simple if you can).

```css
.opendata {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.sticky-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: auto;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

th {
  background: #a0a0a0;
}

td {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="opendata">
  <table id='table'>

    <thead>
      <tr class="sticky-header">
        <th colspan="4" style="font-size: x-large; color: white; text-align: center; background: rgb(6, 60, 122);">
          E V I C T I O N S</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="sticky-header">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Borough</th>
        <th>Zip Code</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
</div>
```

[image: On page load]

[image: After scrolling down in table]

Comment: Please edit your code to show the actual rows so that it represents more accurately your problem

Comment: Some more information might help us reproduce this and try fixes. In any case, I notice that you're using sticky positioning for both of your table rows. Try playing around with the `position: ` property for each row. [Sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning) acts like `position: relative` and then changes into `position: fixed` after it reaches a boundary.

Comment: just add a `z-index` positive to your header

Comment: Also, just in case, blur your image text